# Are there viable and type safe alternatives to the 1:1 type/type-class-instance relation?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, language-agnostic, typeclass, adhoc-polymorphism

This question originally arose during my work on a dynamic JS type validator that relies on dictionary passing style as a rather simple type class mechanism, but I think it also applies to Haskell or other languages having a type class mechanism.

At first I figured it wouldn't be too big a problem to allow several type class instances per type in a setting with dictionary passing style, because I have full control of the type class resolution. But the actual issue seems to maintain type safety not type class resolution, as I am going to demonstrate using the type validator. Since the code is type annotated it is language agnostic to some extend.

```js
// please assume `Number` to be a non-polymorphic `Int` type

Sum.Monoid                          // Monoid<Number>
Prod.Monoid                         // Monoid<Number>
Function.Monoid                     // Monoid<b> -> Monoid<(a -> b)>
Function.Monoid(Prod.Monoid)        // Monoid<(a -> Number)>
Function.Monoid(Prod.Monoid).append // (a -> Number) -> (a -> Number) -> a -> Number
```

When you apply these types type safety is compromized, because it is possible to just write the following contrieved expression without the validator complaining:

```js
Function.Monoid(Prod.Monoid)
  .append(inc) (inc) (Sum.Monoid.empty); // yields 1 ((0 + 1) * (0 + 1)) instead of 4 ((1 + 1) * (1 + 1))
```

In Haskell each instance has its own distinct type to prevent such nonsensical expressions. But having to convert from one type-wrapper to another can be tedious.

Is there a viable, type-safe alternative or is this the very reason why Haskell's designers chose the distinct-type-per-class-instance simplification?

Comment: Isn't this similar to a fundamental 'issue' with subtypes in general? There has to be trust that the subtype (or any convertible type, really) *behaves* to the sensible contract expectations.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would this violate type safety? Surely at worst it simply behaves differently than a coherent typeclass resolution mechanism would, but does not produce any actual type mismatches. ...and why is that a problem? Isn't that exactly what you want to happen? Or, if you don't want to use different instances in different parts of the code, why do you care to provide this non-1:1 feature?

Comment: What's not type safe about this? That you can use `Sum` and `Prod` together without conversion? You can just as well wrap `Number` in different types, that's not unique to Haskell.

Comment: Edward Kmett has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo) that you may find interesting.  It discusses the advantages of "coherence" (the 1:1 relationship between types and type class instances).  You have identified one of many situations where coherence is a really desirable property.

Comment: You could use some string tag (`Symbol` in Haskell, string literal type in TS) to distinguish instances.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one possibility would be to have some sort of scoped instance mechanism. Sort of half-baked, but imagine writing something like this:

```
with Prod.Monoid, Function.Monoid {
    append(inc)(inc)(empty)
}
```

(Say `with X, Y, Z {e}` is short for `with X {with Y {with Z {e}}}`.) Presumably it would then be an error to introduce a second instance for a given class/type pair within that scope:

```
with Prod.Monoid, Function.Monoid {
    -- error: conflicting instances for Number
    --     currently in scope: Prod.Monoid
    --     proposed additional instance: Sum.Monoid
    append(inc)(inc)(with Sum.Monoid {empty})
}
```

But using different instances in different scopes would be allowed:

```
with Prod.Monoid, Function.Monoid {
    append(inc)(inc)
}(with Sum.Monoid {empty})
```

Although the term you proposed would still be possible to write like this, at least it would be explicit about where abstraction boundaries lay.

Making such a feature work correctly in the presence of polymorphism and higher-order functions seems like it could be... exciting. Possibly publishable-research-level exciting. I'd be interested to find out whether a focused attempt can be pushed all the way through.

Comment: This is the kind of idea/sketch I was hoping for. Thank you. I'll try to think it through, maybe even implement it, provided that I get so far.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt I think with this sort of design you'll need to store dictionaries in data structures a lot more, or use some sort of `ST` like trick to keep things from "leaking" out of a scope where they're valid. Think about e.g. Haskell's `Data.Map`. Basically all of the functions for manipulating maps have an `Ord` constraint on the key type, but it won't make sense for a map to be constructed under one `Ord` dictionary and then retrieve items from it using a different `Ord` dictionary. But that could happen if a map can escape a scope, where the uniqueness of instances is only per-scope.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Really the API of `Data.Map` needs to be fundamentally different in such a typeclass system. You need to capture and store the dictionary when you create a map, instead of having an `Ord k` constraint on all the functions. But then what do you do with operations like `merge`? That really wants a guarantee that *both* maps use the same instance, for efficient implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations you can safely use a local explicit instance. In Haskell the `reflection` library can be used to create such a local instance. See the [Reified Monoids](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.6/docs/Data-Reflection.html#g:5) for example.

There was also a paper about building that into the language and perhaps making it more usable and general, but I have not read it: [Coherent Explicit Dictionary Application for Haskell](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/retrieve/519822) by Thomas Winant and Dominique Devriese, here is a quote from their contributions section:

> In this paper, we propose a new form of explicit dictionary
> instantiation that preserves coherence and that is safe with
> respect to global uniqueness of instances, but can be directly
> applied to common use cases.

Comment: The paper is not very satisfying, IMO. Its coherence mechanism smells very brittle to me. I don't really trust it, and I think they'll find it really difficult to maintain in the face of other language extensions. I proposed to add reflection to the language by way of local type declarations, but that was turned down.

Comment: Optics like lenses are closely analogous to local explicit instances as well: a `Fold` behaves sort of like an explicit `Foldable` dictionary, a `Traversal` like a `Traversable` dictionary, and so on. The optic specifies *how* you want to access and/or aggregate, as a composition of “real” instances, starting from some common primitives like `Monoid`, `Functor`, and `Applicative`. But there is no requirement of coherence, and optics libraries tend to “cheat” a little with lawfulness, too. So imo there’s something more principled trying to get out.